# Stuck on the my Joyful Documentation

Tags: c#, documentation

Im writing documentation for .net services.
One of my methods similar to many, returns `List<RoomOccupancy>`

RoomOccupancy is a custom object with fields `RoomNo, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, RentalNo`

My question is what is the best way to display this, and detail the parameters.
How would I represent a list?
Remember this is .net. So maybe readable by any language user.

Some ideas I have thought of:

```
List<RoomOccupancy>  = List<RoomNo, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, RentalNo>
List<RoomOccupancy>  = [RoomNo, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, RentalNo]     (use [] or {}? )
```

Comment: Have a look at Sandcastle. It's a generic way of generating API documentation. Perhaps it will help in this instance.

Comment: This is as off-topic here as scientology is in general - also, the question isn't exactly clear.

Comment: @Mr, This is programming documentation, not documentation on the new Dyson. People have brought auto documentation generation to light - which could be useful. My question is how would I write a list of Roomoccupancy down on paper.

Comment: But the question is purely subjective and discussion-based; that is, the number of ways to skin _this_ cat aren't completely objective and definitive - hence not suitable for this Q&A site, which for starters tends only to scope questions related directly to the programming side of things. The tools being brought up is another thing entirely, but a question revolving around _that_ would (without due care and attention) amount to no more than a "what's best" scenario - also not applicable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like this

```
/// <summary>
/// ...
/// </summary>
/// <returns>List of <see cref="RoomOccupancy"/></returns>
```

That will create a link to the RoomOccupancy class and it's documentation.